# FOSUserBundle: how to allow registration, confirmation but not activation?

Tags: php, symfony, events, fosuserbundle

I'd like the user to register, confirm it's email, but being **activated manually by an administrator**.

Thanks to  [this](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/controller_events.html) page I found the `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED` which is called right after clicking on the confirmation link in the email.

Now I'd like to disable the account (see below).

```
class RegistrationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(            
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED => 'onRegistrationCompleted'
        );
    }

    public function onRegistrationCompleted(UserEvent $event) {
        // registration completed
        // TODO: disable the user. How?
    }
}
```

Or is there any [configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/configuration_reference.html) that I missed?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I can see, inside `FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController::
confirmAction()` user is enabled:

```
/**
 * Receive the confirmation token from user email provider, login the user.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param string  $token
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function confirmAction(Request $request, $token)
{
    /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

    ...

    $user->setConfirmationToken(null);
    $user->setEnabled(true);

    $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM, $event);

    $userManager->updateUser($user);
    ...

    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

    return $response;
}
```

I can think of two things you can do to disable it.

1) write an event listener, that will react on `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED` and disable the user => http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/controller_events.html

2) override `RegistrationController` => https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html

I prefer first option.

```
class RegistrationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /** @var EntityManager */
    private $em;


    /**
     * @param EntityManager $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(            
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED => 'onRegistrationCompleted'
        );
    }

    public function onRegistrationCompleted(UserEvent $event) {
        // registration completed
        // TODO: disable the user. How?
        $user = $event->getUser();
        $user->setEnabled(false);

        $this->em->persist($user);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: You already have `$user` you don't need the use `persist`. `flush` will be enough.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Please use **FilterUserResponseEvent** $event instead of **UserEvent** $event (use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent)